# How to chain pandas get_dummies to separate for multiple delimiters?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, split, one-hot-encoding

I want to convert a column of a data frame which follows the following format:
Elements delimited by ';' with sub-elements delimited by ','

```
E.g. column value:
A a, b; B b; C a; A a, c

The output should be:
Aa | Ab | Bb | Ca | Ac
```

I've tried:

- Chaining str.get_dummies() in the following manner `df.str.get_dummies(sep='; ').columns.str.get_dummies(sep=', ')` which results in a MultiIndex df which I'm not sure how to handle.
- Convert first by ';' and then looping through the resulting dummies and convert by ','. But I'm not sure it's going to work correctly because it will return multiple combinations of the same token (as it's converting iteratively).

Any ideas, or is it the first option the way to go?

Comment: I ended up converting my inputs to `A a; A b; B b; C a; A a; A c` then applied str.get_dummies normally. If there is a more straight forward solution, please still free to share :)